# Interface design in iPhone and iPad using Autolayout?

Tags: iphone, ipad, storyboard, autolayout

I am developing one application to support both iPhone and iPad. i am using Autolayout for interface design in universal storyboard. i have two textFields and one button . i am adding layout constraints for my components like this([image] and [image]). finally my iPhone screen looking like .This how exact i need [image]. But if i run the app in iPad2 the screen is looking like below image [image]. Here textiles and button Width is changing Based on screen size but Textfields and button Height not changing based screen height?. Can anybody tell me how to solve this. I am using Autolayout first time and struggling since morning?

Comment: Text field height not changed ever, for that you have to use TextView instead of TextField. and set Button background color to check button height, if the button height changing after then font size is not changed automatically. so if you want to check this set button back color to see it.

Comment: i am implementing login screen. is it good if i use TextView there?

Comment: No, you have to use textfield and not expecting that the height of textfield is increase, create design that was suitable in iPad.

Comment: Actually i am using Xcode 6.1.1 which we can design one place for all the devices including iPhone and iPad

Comment: use vary for traits in xcode 8. for earlier versions of xcodes use size classes. @BeingLearner

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you have two options here-
1. Under textField, choose the border style I'm attaching below. Then you can change the height of the textField, in the storyboard itself. When you constraint your view, then just don't specify a fixed heigh constraint, and everything should work okay.
2. If you use a textField, then you can just resize it to your needs, and then implement the same constraint specs. But, I personally like textFields more, because they give you options like letting the user enter Secure Text, among other options.

[image: Image Enclosed Here]